# JAX-RS in ServiceMix / Fuse ESB

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, esb, apache-servicemix, cxfrs

I got the below error when I try to install a CXF example from Talend into FuseESB.

```
FuseESB:karaf@root> features:install talend-cxf-example-jaxrs-intro
Error executing command: Can not resolve feature:
Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
   package:(&(package=javax.ws.rs.core)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
      Intro JAX-RS Example Common
   package:(&(package=javax.ws.rs)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
      Intro JAX-RS Example REST Resource Bundle
   package:(&(package=javax.ws.rs)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
      Intro JAX-RS Example Common
   package:(&(package=javax.ws.rs.core)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
      Intro JAX-RS Example REST Resource Bundle
```

I have JSR-311 running

```
FuseESB:karaf@root> list|grep -i 311
[ 165] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   10] Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: JSR-311 API 1.1.1 (1.9.0)
```

How to resolve `Unsatisfied requirement(s)` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuse uses older versions of CXF than Talend does for their ESB and does not currently support CXF 2.7.x which is where the 2.x version of the JAX-RS implementation was added.   The 2.6.x version of CXF that they include only supported JAX-RS 1.1.  You possibly could edit the Talend example to drop it to 1.1 level.  Not sure how well that would work.

Comment: Thx. You saved me a day. After update the project POM to CXF 2.6.0 and reinstall at Apache ServiceMix 4.5, it works!